# gstreamer-1.0 stopping and starting recording pipeline via GUI

Tags: qt, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to write simple video recorder, based on gstreamer framework for my own customboard with ARM processor and Wayland+Qt as window subsystem.
I've created class RecordBin with rec_start slot and rec_stop public method:

```
void RecordBin::rec_start ()
{
  /* Set pipeline to the PLAYING state */
  gst_element_set_state (record_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_print ("setting playing state\n");

  /* Start main loop context */
  g_main_loop_run (rec_loop);
}

void RecordBin::rec_stop ()
{
  /* Set pipeline to the NULL state */
  change_ret = gst_element_set_state (record_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  /* Quit from main loop context */
  g_main_loop_quit (rec_loop);
}
```

This is my slot in mainwindow for play/stop button clicking:

```
void MainWindow::on_recordButton_clicked ()
{
  if (!is_recording) {
    if (window_is_opened == false) {
      cout << "start recording" << endl;

      /* Start recording */
      window_is_opened = true;
      emit start_recording ();
    } else {
      cout << "playing window already opened" << endl;
    }
  } else {
    cout << "recording reset" << endl;

    /* Stop recording */
    record_bin->rec_stop ();
    window_is_opened = false;
  }
}
```

RecordBin class is working in a separate thread (it's realized via QThread), so that glib mainloop context don't blocking Qt main window.
I can't use rec_stop method as slot, because rec_loop blocks the message handling, and when recording starts, it can't be stopped via signal.
But direct call rec_stop is thread unsafe.

Can anybody help me with two questions:
 1. How I should change pipeline state from another thread?
 2. Is it correct to stop recording via changing pipeline state to NULL? Probably I should to send EOS signal on the bus and handling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gst_element_set_state()` is marked as MT safe, so it can be stopped from any thread. I had a problem with setting `gst_element_set_state()` to NULL: `filesink` at the end of pipeline wasn't completing the output files correctly (had to use EOS and catch another event that was confirming that the `filesink` has got that EOS). But NULL works fine for players.

Overall, I'd get rid of the glib mainloop. You can use `gst_bus_set_sync_handler()` to set a callback. In the callback, emit a Qt signal to `RecordBin`. The `RecordBin` will be a `QObject` that lives in the main Qt thread. Process the arriving `GstMessage*` in its slot.